# Does memsql support parametrised query?

Tags: singlestore, prepared-statement

Here is business object sql query

```
SELECT a.AACMP_SK
FROM  WAG_AACMP_MEMBER_PERIOD a
WHERE a.AACMP_SK  =  @prompt('Enter Aacmp Sk:','N','Wag Aacmp Member Period\Aacmp Sk',Mono,Free,Persistent,,User:0)
```

Is there any option to parametrised the query in memsql?

Comment: This looks like a client side option.
What client are you using?

Comment: I have checked , this parametric option is not supported in memsql.. since we are using micro strategy , we need to build the complet sql in  micro startegy and then pass to memsql. thanks